# How to insert multiple row values into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests (
    Test_ID INT,
    TestName VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO Tests VALUES (1, 'SQL Test');
INSERT INTO Tests VALUES (2, 'C# Test');
INSERT INTO Tests VALUES (3, 'Java Test');


CREATE TABLE Users (
    [User_ID] INT,
    UserName VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2, 'Jack');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (3, 'Jane');



CREATE TABLE UserTests (
    ID INT,
    [User_ID] INT,
    Test_ID INT,
    Completed INT);

INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (1, 1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (3, 1, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (4, 2, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (5, 2, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (6, 2, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (7, 3, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (8, 3, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO UserTests VALUES (9, 3, 3, 1);
```

I would like to create some rule/trigger so that when a new user gets added to the Users table, an entry for each `Test` and that user's `Id` will get added to the `UserTests` table.

Something like this if the new user ID is 5:

```
INSERT dbo.UserTest
       (USER_ID, TEST_ID, Completed)
VALUES 
       (5, SELECT TEST_ID FROM Tests, 0)
```

That syntax is of course wrong but to give an idea of what I expect to happen.

So I expect that statement to add these values to the `UserTests` table:

```
User ID| Test ID| Completed 
5      | 1      | 0
5      | 2      | 0
5      | 3      | 0
```

Comment: Why not just store completed tests in `UserTests`?  I don't see a reason to pre-populate it with all tests.  In particular, this becomes a maintenance problem if new tests are added or if there are eligibility requirements for certain tests.

Comment: Well because the user should see a list of all available tests on his/her page and the list should have all completed/non-completed tests. If there is a better way to do just that? I understand there will be a lot of "blank" entries for the non-completed entries.

Comment: . . There is likely to be a better way.  You should ask another question with the particular details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use after trigger for user table.

```
Create Trigger tr_user on Users 
After Insert 
AS Begin
   INSERT UserTest(USER_ID, TEST_ID, Completed)
   Select I.USER_ID, t.TEST_ID, 0
   From Inserted I, Tests t
END
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but will that not only insert 1 record into UserTests? Instead of one record for each available Test?

Comment: for each record that inserted in User table, inserted total rows from tests table with inserted user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Fiddle that finds missing records and inserts them.

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac190/5)

The `SELECT`:

```
select u.user_id, t.test_id, 0 as Completed
from users u 
cross join tests t
where not exists (
        select 1 
        from usertests ut 
        where ut.user_id = u.user_id and ut.test_id = t.test_id)
```

Adding `insert into UserTests (User_Id, Test_Id, Completed)` before the select will insert these records.

You can add a user id on to the where clause to do it for a single user if required. It is re-runnable so it won't re-insert test ids for a user that already has them, but will add new ones if new tests are introduced.